# Can Superman fly through solid rock?

Tags: dc, superman

Can Superman fly through solid rock? (using force and destruction) If so, when was he first portrayed doing this?

1. in a comic
2. in a movie

Ideally I'd like a picture of Superman flying through solid rock. It could be from a comic or a movie. I've spent some time googling, but I've not been able to find any relevant results.

Comment: It depends on how you define "fly through." With Superman, it's a destructive process (unlike how the Vision from the Avengers could fly through solid rock intangibly), as shown in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: @RDFozz - Yes, I'm interested in destructive flying.

Comment: I assumed as much from your acceptance of the answer :-) - just wanted to clarify the point for others who see this Q&A later.

Comment: Because the question was so specific about flying through rock, I'm leaving this as a comment.  In the '50's TV show episode [The Mysterious Cube](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0506628/) Superman "vibrates" through an impregnable material without destroying it or making a hole.  For some reason I can clearly remember seeing that particular scene on TV, but not any others

Comment: @PeterM -- you remember it because, like Jimmy, you were afraid he'd gotten stuck.

Comment: Oh wow i must be showing my age but i remember seeing that episode  The Mysterious Cube.  Thanks for the reminder Peter M.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Superman flies (down) through solid rock and metal in [Superman Vol. 1 #43: *The Molten World*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_43)

[image]

Probably the earliest instance of his "burrowing" through rock and soil is from [Superman Vol. 1 #11: *The Yellow Plague*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_11)

[image]

And we see Supergirl and Krypto (who share basically the same power-set as Superman) tunnelling through a mountain in [Action Comics 258: *Supergirl's Farewell to Earth!*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_258)

[image]

---

In the movies he drills down to Luthor's underground lair through asphalt and bedrock in  *Superman* (1978)

[image]

And 'flies' through solid rock in [*Man of Steel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(film))

---

On TV you can see him tunnelling at speed through the side of a mountain in [Justice League of America #1: *Between Two Armies*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y4VORN6YOw&feature=youtu.be&t=251)

[image]

Comment: It figures that Superman would be more worried about her revealing her existence to Krypto than destroying a mountain.

Comment: Probably he can always build another one.

Comment: @DarthHunterix Can he? I don't remember him doing so, but if building a mountain is just putting heaps of material into place and pushing it hard enough to form it into something mountainous looking, sure, probably.

Comment: @Adamant   Driling two tunnels each less than four feet in diamter through a mountain thousands of feet high and probably miles long and wide doesn't seem like destroying or undermining it to me.  What do Supergirl and Krypto do the rock?  Maybe vaporize it, or maybe knock it back behind them as they burrow, which would leave most of their tunnels filled up behind them.  In which case Superman would just have to plug up two or four small caves and the mountain is almost as good as new.

Comment: He doesn’t really _drill_ down to Luthor’s underground lair in _Superman_ as much as he starts turning on the spot and then immediately a hole about two feet in diameter magically appears in the ground. His feet have barely started revolving, and the hole is about six times the size of the area covered by his spinning feet. Looks like a sinkhole waiting to happen. Good thing Superman made the authorities aware of it, albeit in a somewhat ostentatious manner.

Comment: Since the movie first came out, some friends and I debate whether Superman is purely drilling or simultaneously using heat vision.  The flash of periphery red could be heat vision or just the fast-moving cape.
A better scene from "Superman" , vis-a-vis the original question, is when Superman is crashing-drilling-flying thru rock to the base of the San Andreas Fault.

Comment: @Blaze His cape is Super-sharp and helps him drill!

Comment: @Mast If we go by the movies, he has super rebuilding vision (aka reverse the footage vision).

Comment: In the "burrowing" Superman Vol. 1 #11 case, it looks like he may be drilling as well, given the curved movement lines.

Comment: @JacobC. - I thought so, which is why I included the panel from Superman #43